# Number of X screens corresponding to number of "Screen" sections in xorg.conf file for multi-monitor configuration

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor

I want to set up a multi-monitor configuration where two "landscape" oriented monitors one above the other and two "portrait" oriented monitors one right of the other combine into a single large screen.

I'm trying to create a `xorg.conf` file that would provide a single X screen for multiple (four) monitors attached to several (two) videocards (NVidia) on the same machine (Ubuntu 11.10).

I stumbled upon a `xorg.conf` manual that states that the `Screen` section is the binding of a `Monitor` and a `Device`. I don't understand how to provide the idea that one `Screen` must be composed of several `Monitor`s.

I don't want to use `Xinerama` or `TwinView` since it don't meet my requirements for hardware acceleration. I used `nvidia-settings` but it doesn't honor the rotation settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with RandR (`xrandr`)?

Comment: Can you include how to actually do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, `nvidia-settings` does NOT (sic!) include `RandR` control in their GUI configuration. I needed to produce a bulk `xorg.conf` with `Option "RandRRotation" "yes"` to make it active. Once activated, a control line in `nvidia-settings` GUI appeared allowing one of the `Screen`s to be rotated. However, the Nvidia's utility itself doesn't honor it's own rotation settings, displaying all the monitors in the monitor layout tab in non-rotated form. Also, RandR rotation is not applied until login, which is inacceptable.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Probably my comment above answers (at least partly) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Screen to define the size of the total desktop to be displayed by the various monitors. It can point to one of the three monitors, each in its own section. The options in the additional monitors describe their relative positions.

Although xrandr isn't useful to you as a solution, it can be useful to try various resolutions and positions. Once you have it configured the way you want you can describe the configuration in xorg.conf and restart X. You may find a useful example [here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors).

Answer (score 0):

As you note - you can't use `Xinerama` or `TwinView` and get X-compositing on your screens. What you really want to do involves multiple `Device` entries in `xorg.conf` for the same device and/or `nvidia's` `mosaic` mode. I went through this just the other day after rearranging the living room to accomodate a projector and it is *not* intuitive. I wound up doing it bit by bit with several false starts, but for one video card and two displays my `xorg.conf` came out like [this](http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/text/xorg.txt).

The *one screen* used to define metamodes is a sort of indirection. The `nvidia` driver and/or `RandR` extension adds together the display area of one or more physical screens and addresses that display area as a single *virtual* screen. [Here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/304.43/README/configtwinview.html) is a link to the relevant section of `nvidia`'s readme. And here's what mine actually look like:

[image: two xdisplays]

As you can see the two screens are one - but the resolutions per constituent screen are not evenly matched - so while that white bar at the bottom left shows up in a screen shot, it's not on my display. My display *fills* both of my screens. And here's a closer look at the `nvidia-settings`:

[image: nvidia-settings]

If you look at my own [xorg.txt](http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/text/xorg.txt) file you'll likely notice it is auto-generated. I got it to work by first powering off all of the displays but one and then, at a regular console, I ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig` for a baseline `xorg.conf` and, after starting `X`, I opened `nvidia-settings` and powered on my screens. It was not a scientifically perfect process, admittedly, but the result is satisfactory.

Another problem I had that you may or may not have was the sound EDID extensions passed over the HDMI cables from my displays. I use the analog out from my computer and there was another very annnoying few hours spent trying to convince ALSA/Pulse to ignore those extra `intel-hda-audio` devices. So I rewrote the EDIDs to appear as DVI outputs - essentially disabling the computer's detection of the displays' audio sinks. If you do run into similar issues, I humbly recommend [this little gem](http://analogbit.com/software/edid_disable_exts) to automatically do the same.

Last, the [Arch Linux wiki Nvidia page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Multiple_monitors) was very useful for me - there are lots of examples and detailed explanations there.